# How can I examine each digit of a BigInteger in Java?

Tags: java, biginteger

How can I examine each digit (`System.out.println()` each digit, for instance) of a BigInteger in Java? Is there any other way other than converting it to a string?

Comment: The digits of a BigInteger are likely not stored in base 10, so there's probably no other way than to inspect the characters of the string representation.

Comment: Only string can hold the number that a BigInteger can handle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Straight-forward code prints digits from the last towards the first:

```
private static void printDigits(BigInteger num) {
    BigInteger[] resultAndRemainder;
    do {
        resultAndRemainder = num.divideAndRemainder(BigInteger.TEN);
        System.out.println(Math.abs(resultAndRemainder[1].intValue()));
        num = resultAndRemainder[0];
    } while (num.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) != 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`BigInteger` API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) do not appear to provide any functionality as such.  Moreover, the numbers are quite likely not represented in base 10 (since it would be quite inefficient).  So it is most likely that the only way to inspect the decimal digits of a BigInteger is to look at its string representation.

Comment: can bigInteger be converted to integer array ,then also it would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

You could of course use basic math to calculate each digit. Especially the method `divideAndRemainder` might help here. But I doubt, that this is more efficient than converting to a String and examing the characters. `BigInteger` math is more expensive than plain `int` or `long` math after all.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way you could do it is converting it into a String and verify each char. Here is an example:

```
BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger("123");
String bigIntegerValue = bigInteger.toString();
for(int i = 0; i < bigIntegerValue.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println(bigIntegerValue.charAt(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to examine each bit in your biginteger using [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) like this,

```
 BitSet bitSet = BitSet.valueOf(bigInteger.toByteArray());
```

Answer (score -2):

It seems pretty simple what you need to do get each digit of a number.
create a loop that tracks if you number is greater then ten and then preform a mod 10 operation on it and then divide by ten.

```
 while (num >10)
{
     System.out.println(num%10);
     num = num/10;

}
```

Comment: For a `BigInteger`, you need the methods, `mod`, `divide`, `compareTo` instead of the operators. But in principle that works.

Comment: You also need to accommodate the high-order digit.